# Retrieve coordinates from a Geometry type table

Tags: mysql, geometry, geospatial

The query I have used to insert the coordinates:

```
INSERT INTO `area` VALUES (PolygonFromText('POLYGON((".$polygon."))'))")
```

The query I have used to get coordinates back:

```
SELECT CAST(AsText(polygon) AS char) AS p from `area`
```

What I got back is:
POLYGON((40.6524347950336 22.9509570396729,40.6304214047297 22.9454638756104,40.6123102760868 22.9640033043213,40.6113980749889 22.9895808494873,40.6524347950336 22.9509570396729))

Is there a better way or another way, maybe altering my query to only get the coordinates ?

Comment: You are getting polygon in [WKT format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text). Maybe [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24888/accessing-coordinates-of-polygon) can be helpful.

Comment: I am using MySQL not postGIS, so I think ST_ function will not work for me.